# How to add custom layout elements to listView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have this custom layout element

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/secondEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/thirdEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtn"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_500"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_control_point_24"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:checked="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

It's basically just three edit texts and a button, is there a way to create a list and progressively add elements of this type to it? I've seen ways of doing it with a cursorAdapter but I believe those can only be used for sqlLite queries and such, but I want to start the list with just one element and let the button add extra elements of the same type.

Comment: You can do it by the code into the Activity or Fragment. But You need to specify the in which circumstance the new button will be added to the list.

Comment: don't use listview, use recyclerview

Comment: Simply follow the instruction: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/adapting-to-listadapter-341da4218f5b. it will be a great help